# Proof that $(V_{\omega},\in)\models ZFC-Inf+\neg Inf$.

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

I have a question regarding models of set theory.

As the title say I am trying to prove that $(V_{\omega},\in)\models ZFC-Inf+\neg Inf$, that is $V_\omega$ is a model for all the $ZFC$ axioms except from the axiom of infinity, where it is a model of its negation.

Now, I think I proved everything right except from the axiom schema of replacement and the axiom of choice, where I don't really know where to start. Can you guys help me here?

Also, I am not entirely sure of the proof I gave for the Axiom Schema of Separation. Here's what I did. Given any formula $\phi(x)$ and any $a\in V_{\omega}$, I need to check that $B:=\{c\in a : \phi^{V_{\omega}}(c)\}$ is a set, i.e. an element of $V_{\omega}$. Now, $a\in V_{\omega}$ implies that $a\in V_n$ for some $n\in\omega$. We have now that $B\subseteq a\in V_n$, by transitivity of $V_n$ we conclude that $B\subseteq V_n$, but this implies that $B\in V_{n+1}$ and so $B\in V_{\omega}$ and this concludes the proof. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Axiom of Choice:  This is a special case of a theorem of $\mathbf{ZF}$ that says that if $X$ is a **finite** set of non-empty sets, there exists a choice function $f:X\to \cup X$ such that $f(z)\in z$ for all $z\in X$.  It is proved by induction on $n=|X|$.  If $X=\emptyset$ there is nothing to do.  Else, assume there is a choice function for all sets of size $n$.  Let $X$ be a set of size $n+1$.  Take any $x_0\in X$ and let $X'=X\setminus\{x_0\}$.  Then $|X'|=n$.  By the induction hypothesis there is a function $f_{X'}$ with domain $X'$ such that $f_{X'}(z)\in z$ for all $z\in X'$.  Now take some $y_0\in x_0$ and let $f_X=f_{X'}\cup\{(x_0,y_0)\}$.  Then $f_X$ is a choice function on $X$.

For a set $X\in V_\omega$, $X$ is hereditarily-finite, so $|X|\in\omega$, and you can apply the theorem above to get a choice function.  Since $X$ is hereditarily finite, all members of the transitive closure of $X$ are members of $V_\omega$, so a choice function built this way stays entirely in $V_\omega$.

Axiom schema of Replacement: This is similar to separation, but slightly more complicated.  Say you have a formula $\varphi(x,y,p_1,\dots,p_n)$ whose free variables are among $x,y,p_1,\dots,p_n$ and a set $X\in V_\omega$ such that
$$(V_\omega,\in)\models \forall x,y_1,y_2 (x\in X\land\varphi[y_1/y]\land\varphi[y_2/y]\rightarrow y_1=y_2)$$
Then
$$(V,\in)\models \forall x,y_1,y_2(x\in V_\omega\land y_1\in V_\omega\land y_2\in V_\omega \land x\in X\land\varphi^{V_\omega}[y_1/y]\land\varphi^{V_\omega}[y_2/y]\rightarrow y_1=y_2)$$
Now, using that $X\subseteq V_\omega$, letting $\psi = \varphi^{V_\omega} \land y\in p_{n+1}$ and assigning the additional parameter $p_{n+1}$ to take on the value $V_\omega$ we can conclude
$$(V,\in)\models \forall x,y_1,y_2 (x\in X\land\psi[y_1/y]\land\psi[y_2/y]\rightarrow y_1=y_2)$$
Now we use Replacement globally on $(V,\in)$ to conclude
$$(V,\in)\models \exists B\forall y(y\in B\leftrightarrow \exists x (x\in X\land \psi))$$
The set $B$ obtained this way satisfies the requirement of the axiom schema of Replacement for $\varphi$ relative to $(V_\omega,\in)$.

Axiom of Separation: I agree with your proof.

Comment: Thank you for the exhausting response, but there's something I don't understand. Regarding AC, I agree with your proof, but it proves that we have a choice function on a generic element $X\in V_{\omega}$. Shouldn't we prove that a choice function exists for an arbitrary family of sets in $V_{\omega}$, say $\mathcal{F}:=\{X_i: i\in I, \forall i\in I \,\,\, X_i\in V_{\omega}\}$ ?

Comment: @cento18:  The index set $I$ also has to be a set in the model.  If $(V_\omega,\in)$ is your model then the index set $I$ must be a member of $V_\omega$.  Take $X$ in the paragraph on AC to be $\mathcal{F}$ in your notation.  Since $I\in V_\omega$, $I$ is a finite set.

Comment: Ok I get your point, but does this mean that it is impossible to have an infinite family of sets all belonging to $V_{\omega}$?

Comment: @cento18:  An infinite set each of whose members are in $V_\omega$ cannot be $\in V_\omega$, because all members of $V_\omega$ are finite sets.  In particular, a choice function for such a set cannot be $\in V_\omega$ because it makes infinitely many choices.

Comment: @cento18 $V_\omega$ is an infinite family of sets all belonging to $V_\omega$. But $V_\omega\notin V_\omega$.